# Bash shell replacing one character with multiple characters on string

Tags: bash, shell, replace

Working with spanish words comes with special characters like á, É or ñ.

In order to consult a site for etimologies, I have to convert strings from "dinámica" to "dina.mica", but when using any of the next lines I obtain "dinamica" without the dot.

How should I write this to pass 2 characters and not one?

```
echo "dinámica" | tr áÁ a.
echo "dinámica" | tr áÁ "a."
```

Thanks.

Comment: I found a way. string="dinámica", then new_string=${string//[áÁ]//a.}. And that does it.

Comment: This is close, but would produce `din/a.mica` and not `dina.mica`. If you fix this, I suggest that you provide your solution as an answer. It is perfectly legal to answer your own questions.

Comment: You are right. I wrote it wrong here and will answer correctly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This makes the work:

```
string="dinámica"
new_string="${string//[áÁ]/a.}"
```

Echo to new_string is "dina.mica"

Thanks.

Comment: The closing brace is misplaced. I think you meant `new_string="${string//[áÁ]/a.}"`.